# How to run files in parallel in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing

How do I achieve [**I want to process a bunch of files in parallel, and when one finishes, I want to start the next. And I want to make sure there are exactly 5 jobs running at a time @ Wooledge.org**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I_want_to_process_a_bunch_of_files_in_parallel.2C_and_when_one_finishes.2C_I_want_to_start_the_next._And_I_want_to_make_sure_there_are_exactly_5_jobs_running_at_a_time.) using Ruby?

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 5 command
```

or

```
find . -print0 | parallel -0 command | use_output_if_needed
```

or

```
for i in *.log ; do
  echo "$i"
  [...do other needed stuff...]
  sem -j10 gzip $i ";" echo done
done
sem --wait
```

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ruby-pool gem](https://github.com/meh/ruby-thread).

Been using it for a couple of months and love it!

Let me know if you have any questions!

**Example Code**

```
require 'thread/pool'

pool = Thread.pool(5)

all_files.each do |f|
  pool.process {
    # Do Stuff
  }
end

pool.shutdown
```